# php mb_substr() function causes json_encode() to fail

Tags: php, json, multibyte

```
<?php
  $original = "ÄäÖö";
  $shortened = mb_substr( $original, 0, 1 );
  echo json_encode( $original );// OK
  echo json_encode( $shortened );// PHP Warning:  json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument...
?>
```

Seems like mb_substr malforms the multibyte string! Am I missing something here or misusing mb_substr somehow?

Comment: What is the mb internal character encoding set to?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set default internal encoding to UTF-8.

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

It worked great for me.

Output:

```
"\u00c4\u00e4\u00d6\u00f6""\u00c4"
```